# how to get to the parameter in the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, javascript-objects

I've the result from SOAP (jQuery ajax )

```
[...]
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
[...]
```

and **data** looks like this:

```
​d: {…}
​​__type: "uMES.Logic.Object.Operation"
​​description: "OK"
​​operationId: 123654
​​status: 0
​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​<prototype>: {…
```

how to get information about ***"operationId"***  variable in javascript/jquery

I tried:

```
console.log(data.operationId);
```

but it doesn't work, I get "undefined".

--

Best regards

Chris

Comment: I know probably not the case, but you haven't forgot the semicolon, right?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - do you get an error?

Comment: when I write console.log(data.operationId); I get "undefined"

Comment: @ssnake can you post the result of console.log(Object.keys(data)); ?

Comment: @omidh result: 
(1) […]
0: "d"
length: 1
<prototype>: Array []